# Error Caused by: org.voltdb.client.ProcCallException: Procedure XXXXXX is not present in the catalog

Tags: java, database, stored-procedures, voltdb

I have some procedures compiled in VoltDB and I am testing an java API connected to VoltDB to call this procedures, but a have this error: "Caused by: org.voltdb.client.ProcCallException: Procedure proc_telefonos_obtenerlada2digitos is not present in the catalog. This can happen if a catalog update removing the procedure occurred after the procedure was submitted but before the procedure was executed."

[ERROR] 2024-02-19 18:55:00.705 [main] App - Excepci¾n no controlada:
java.sql.SQLException: General Provider Error (UNEXPECTED_FAILURE): 'Procedure proc_telefonos_obtenerlada2digitos is not present in the catalog. This can happen if a catalog update removing the procedure occurred after the procedure was submitted but before the procedure was executed.'
at org.voltdb.jdbc.SQLError.get(SQLError.java:60) ~[api.telefonos-2.6.2.jar:?]
at org.voltdb.jdbc.JDBC4Statement$VoltSQL.execute(JDBC4Statement.java:141) ~[api.telefonos-2.6.2.jar:?]
at org.voltdb.jdbc.JDBC4Statement.executeQuery(JDBC4Statement.java:458) ~[api.telefonos-2.6.2.jar:?]
at org.voltdb.jdbc.JDBC4PreparedStatement.executeQuery(JDBC4PreparedStatement.java:123) ~[api.telefonos-2.6.2.jar:?]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:52) ~[api.telefonos-2.6.2.jar:?]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyCallableStatement.executeQuery(HikariProxyCallableStatement.java) ~[api.telefonos-2.6.2.jar:?]
at com.coppel.dal.CofetelDALJdbc.getLada2Digitos(CofetelDALJdbc.java:59) ~[api.telefonos-2.6.2.jar:?]
at com.coppel.models.CofetelModel.obtenerLada2Digitos(CofetelModel.java:68) ~[api.telefonos-2.6.2.jar:?]
at com.coppel.models.CofetelModel.inicializarCatalogo(CofetelModel.java:162) ~[api.telefonos-2.6.2.jar:?]
at com.coppel.telefonos.ApiTelefonosModelos.InicializarCatalogos(ApiTelefonosModelos.java:34) ~[api.telefonos-2.6.2.jar:?]
at com.coppel.telefonos.ApiTelefonosModelos.inicializar(ApiTelefonosModelos.java:80) ~[api.telefonos-2.6.2.jar:?]
at com.coppel.main.App.main(App.java:121) [api.telefonos-2.6.2.jar:?]
Caused by: org.voltdb.client.ProcCallException: Procedure proc_telefonos_obtenerlada2digitos is not present in the catalog. This can happen if a catalog update removing the procedure occurred after the procedure was submitted but before the procedure was executed.
at org.voltdb.client.ClientImpl.internalSyncCallProcedure(ClientImpl.java:480) ~[api.telefonos-2.6.2.jar:?]
at org.voltdb.client.ClientImpl.callProcedureWithClientTimeout(ClientImpl.java:319) ~[api.telefonos-2.6.2.jar:?]
at org.voltdb.client.ClientImpl.callProcedureWithClientTimeout(ClientImpl.java:290) ~[api.telefonos-2.6.2.jar:?]
at org.voltdb.jdbc.JDBC4ClientConnection.execute(JDBC4ClientConnection.java:349) ~[api.telefonos-2.6.2.jar:?]
at org.voltdb.jdbc.JDBC4Statement$VoltSQL.execute(JDBC4Statement.java:120) ~[api.telefonos-2.6.2.jar:?]

I checked in voltDB and the procedure exists, even I can exec it in the sqlcmd.
¿what can I do to solve this? I´m new using voltDB, thank you [sqlcmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CMXVB.png)